# pass variable through url to view

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to pass my input text value through url when i click my submit button.

**views.py**

```
def profile(request,username): 
        current_user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    return render_to_response ('profiles/search.html', {'current_user':current_user, 
    context_instance=RequestContext(request),)
```

**search.html**

```
<form action="{%url 'profiles:profile'  username=user.username  %}" id="search_by_username" method ="get">
<input type="text" name = "searchname" class="text"  placeholder="Search by username" />
<input type="submit" value="button" />
</form>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^view/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.profile, name="profile"),
```

after clicking the submit button ,Iam getting a url like this:

```
192.168.1.33:8000/profiles/view/abraham/?searchname=merlin
```

Here abraham is the loggin user but actually i need to search for merlin.So how can i replace abraham by merlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a form field to automatically put its value into the URL the form is submitting to (except by mucking about with the form in Javascript, which would be horrible).

But as you can see, you do get that data in the request parameters: since you're doing a GET, it's in `request.GET['searchname']`. So why don't you drop the `username` parameter to the URL/view in the first place, and just use that?

Comment: thanks a lot for responding my question.iam new to python and django.so is there any mistake please forgive me.Now i edited my form action like this:   '<form action="{%url 'profiles:profile'  username=request.GET['searchname']  %}" id="search_by_username" method ="get">'

Comment: What? I didn't say you made any mistakes. I gave you some advice for solving the problem.